# Dedekind cuts and multiplication

Tags: real-numbers

A common way to define multiplication for Dedekind cuts is to first define it for pairs of positive reals, and to then extend it to general pairs of reals case by case. Is there an alternative definition that is less ham-fisted?

edit: I suppose one way is to identify the positive and negative reals with the upward- and downward-portions of their cuts, respectively. Multiplication can then just be defined element-wise... but I think this complicates the other elementary operation, addition.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't call the definition ham-fisted.  2. The power of Dedekind cuts comes from the ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$, but multiplication by a negative reverses that ordering, so there needs to be some maneuvering to get around this problem.

Comment: alternative definition of the product of Dedekind cuts, or an alternative construction of the reals in which the product is more fluently given?

Comment: @IttayWeiss What I had in mind was the former, but I would appreciate either.

Comment: JH Conway remarked of the Dedekind cut construction that some proofs require consideration of 64 cases and that no-one would actually have checked so many cases by hand. A pleasant alternative is to use the Dedekind construction to construct the additive structure of the reals and then derive the multiplicative structure by an analysis of the order-preserving morphisms of the additive group.

Comment: @RobArthan do you have a reference for Conway's comment about Dedekind cuts requiring 64 cases checked?

Comment: @IttayWeiss: I don't have the book to hand to check, but I  believe you'll find it fairly early on in "On Numbers and Games".

Comment: @RobArthan, yes I found the reference in "On Numbers and Games" but it's not clear (to me) there that Conway actually refers to a proof of the Dedekind construction which requires 64 cases. Thanks in any case :) I was hoping you had a different source in mind.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, it seems unlikely to entirely avoid some sign considerations in the multiplication of Dedekind cuts. This is so because of the direction reversal when multiplying by a negative number, and so, in some sense, the two halves of a Dedekind cut need to switch place, being the source of the mild headache.

There are plenty of constructions of the real numbers (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03467) for a survey of 20 constructions), some of which give more direct and simple definitions of the algebraic operations. In particular, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.04348) for a detailed construction using minimal rational filters for a construction in which the definition of addition and multiplication (as well as the order structure) are very straightforward.